# Remove the history tag?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5901/francis-crick-and-the-usefulness-of-genes-as-compared-to-molecular-biochemistr) was recently migrated to another site. I found this disappointing but, regardless, if such questions are not on-topic here, perhaps the [history](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag should be removed. Thoughts?

Comment: Why is that disappointing? [hsm.se] is meant for questions like this. This question has nothing to do with biology *per se*. The post was already closed as off-topic before I migrated it to [hsm.se].

Comment: @WYSIWYG It's disappointing because I think such questions should be on-topic here. Anyways, that's beside the point, which is that having a history tag is pointless and confusing if such questions are off-topic.